# How can I create a Word document in office 365 / 'OneDrive for Business' using c#

Tags: c#, office365

I want to create a word document with some content in it into Office 365/'OneDrive for Business' suing Asp.net MVC and C#, how can I achieve the same?

Comment: I received a down vote for this question. I am fine with it as long as I get the reason for giving this down vote.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have two different tasks you want to achieve here - first, creating a docx file programmatically, then second, uploading that file to Office 365.

The first part - how to create a docx file - can be done in several different ways. Do you just want to create a blank file? If so, you could just script the file creation (`touch myfile.docx` or whatnot) -- and then you are done. Want to create a document with content? My suggestion then would be to read up on the Open XML SDKs, which allow developers to manually assemble docx files. There is a fair amount of documentation on this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/cc850833(v=office.15).aspx), as well as [openxmldeveloper.org](http://openxmldeveloper.org/).

Once you have the file, you can upload it to Office 365 using the [Office 365 Files APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/files-rest-operations#FileresourceCreateorupdateafile). The 365 APIs have [C# client libraries](http://blogs.office.com/2014/05/12/net-and-javascript-libraries-for-office-365-apis/), which you can use to upload the file.